# Proper Local Hardhat Deploy and Transaction: function call to a non-contract account

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I am trying to test out this [contract](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/english-auction/) function by function to interpret how each call works and while I am able to deploy the contract, I receive this error message, `Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account`, which I found to be related to the fact that the deploy script kills the process once the script is run, but I'm wondering why it would complete prior to my transaction call. In addition, does running this script open and close a hardhat node? I had a node running in the background, but it doesn't seem like it interacts with that one.

**`run-english-acution.js` Log:**

```
Compilation finished successfully
Contract address: 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180bb3
Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
    at EnglishAuction.start (contracts/EnglishAuction.sol:47)
```

**`run-english-auction.js`:**

```
const contractDeploy = async () => {
    const englishAuctionContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('EnglishAuction');
    const englishAuctionContract = await englishAuctionContractFactory.deploy(
        "0xf39....",
        1,
        5
    )
    await englishAuctionContract.deployed();
    console.log('Contract address:', englishAuctionContract.address);

    // English Auction - Transaction
    const startTxn = await englishAuctionContract.start();
    await startTxn.wait();
};

const runContractDeploy = async () => {
    try {
        await contractDeploy();
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

runContractDeploy();
```

**`EnglishAuction.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC721 {
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint tokenId
    ) external;

    function transferFrom(
        address,
        address,
        uint
    ) external;

}

contract EnglishAuction {
    IERC721 public nft;
    uint public nftId;
    bool public started;
    bool public ended;
    uint public endAt;
    address payable public seller;
    uint public highestBid;
    
    event Start();
    event Bid(address indexed sender, uint amount);

    constructor(address _nft, uint _nftId, uint _startingBid) {
        nft = IERC721(_nft);
        nftId = _nftId;
        seller = payable(msg.sender);
        highestBid = _startingBid;
    }
    
    function start() external {
        require(!started, "auction started");
        require(msg.sender == seller, "not seller");

        nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), nftId);
        started = true;
        endAt = block.timestamp + 7 days;

        emit Start();
    }
}
```